Python async signal handling
Python async code:
import asyncio
from asyncio import StreamReader, StreamWriter

# send messages with nc localhost 7000
async def echo(reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter): 
    peername = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    connection_id = f"{peername[0]}:{peername[1]}"  # Using peername as connection ID
    print(f'Open connection to {connection_id=}')

    while data := await reader.readline():
        print(f'Received data {data=}')
        data = data.decode()
        writer.write(f'Return as uppercase:{data.upper()}'.encode())
        await writer.drain()


async def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=7000):
    print(f'Server running on {host}:{port}')
    server = await asyncio.start_server(echo, host, port)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

How can I add signal handling, fro graceful shutdown (CTRL+C(SIGINIT) and SIGTERM) to above code ?
Main is that I want to close writer in echo, but keep in mind that there cloud be others async def outside of await asyncio.start_server(echo, host, port) I am just starting with easy example.


The basic pattern to allow a controlled cleanup is to catch the CancelledError (without "swallowing" it unless there is a good reason):

async def worker():
    try:
        ... do work here ...
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        ... do cleanup here ...
        raise


Use a taskgroup (Python 3.11+) to run all your tasks (workers) if you have more of them. It will exit only after all its members has exited.

The SIGINT (ctrl-C, KeyboardInterrupt) is handled by asyncio itself. This article goes into details. Install handlers for additional signal(s) you want (e.g. SIGTERM) and translate a caught signal to cancellation.


Here is a simple demo:
import asyncio, signal

async def worker():
    try:
        while True:
            print("working")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("cleaning up")
        raise

def set_signal_handler(signum, task_to_cancel):
    def handler(_signum, _frame):
        asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(task_to_cancel.cancel)
    signal.signal(signum, handler)

async def main():
    this_task = asyncio.current_task()
    try:
        set_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, task_to_cancel=this_task)
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg: 
            tg.create_task(worker())
            #tg.create_task(worker2())
            #tg.create_task(worker3())
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    # TODO: reset the signal handler(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

A signal will cancel the task running main with the taskgroup. A cancelled taskgroup cancels all its members. The CancelledError is then stopped from propagating from the taskgroup.
The only "trick" is to use call_soon_threadsafe from within the handler. No threads are involved, but a signal may come at any time. The signal handler's code must not interfere with the code just interrupted which can be any code including asyncio internals. A threadsafe function is a perfect fit.

UPDATE: In reaction to the comment about synchronized shutdown, here is a really verbose example of a "shutdown manager" to play with. Here it shuts down tasks sequentially in given order. Anything more advanced must be programmed. I use this technique in my programs quite often. It completely takes over the SIGINT handling. A special bonus: automatic shutdown on error.
import asyncio, signal

_do_shutdown = asyncio.Event()

async def worker(w):
    try:
        while True:
            print(f"{w} working")
            await asyncio.sleep((w+3)/5)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"{w} cleaning up")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"{w} done")
        raise
    except Exception:
        _do_shutdown.set()   # on error start shutdown
        raise

def _handler(_signum, _frame):
    asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(_do_shutdown.set)

async def shutdown_manager(tasklist):
    saved_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _handler)
    await _do_shutdown.wait()
    print("-- shutdown started")
    for task in tasklist:
        name = task.get_name()
        if task.done():
            print(f"{name} not running")
        else:
            print(f"cancelling {name} now")
            task.cancel()
        try:
            await task
            print(f"{name} exited")
        except asyncio.CancelledError as exc:
            print(f"{name} cancelled, exited")
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"{name} crashed with {exc!r}")
    print("-- shutdown finished")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, saved_handler)

async def main():
    print("press ctrl-C to stop")
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(worker(i), name=f'task #{i}')
        for i in range(3)]
    await shutdown_manager(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


thanks.
I have "one Task", that will start 3x other tasks  and then I do await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED), basically waiting until some is completed first, and do this is loop, not sure if this is best way to do it in async, feel free to comment.

My "problem" is that I need to have some kind of synchronization between one Task, and other 3x tasks. Like, if one Task is in some state then, I prefer to wait some time (few seconds) until I get response from one of/or many other 3x tasks, but only for few seconds because it may not occur. For this I see that just sending cancel is not optimal.
My idea is to use async.Event and lot of code for synchronization.
Is there some better way, this remind me on threads synchronization and  hope that there is something easier in async.

@WebOrCode look at the update.
